# How to pass a date to a function with Date-FNS?

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

I'm using the Date-FNS library to get the [difference between two dates in minutes](https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/differenceInMinutes). Why does *minutesDifference* return **NaN** if the date get passed like this: `getDateTime(2018, 3, 4, 15, 30, 0)` ?

```
getDateTime: function (customDate) { 
var minutesDifference = differenceInMinutes(new Date(customDate), new Date()) 
console.log('minutesDifference: ' + minutesDifference) 
}
```

But this works (hard coded version without *customDate*):

```
getDateTime: function () { 
var minutesDifference = differenceInMinutes(new Date(2018, 3, 4, 15, 30, 0), new Date())
console.log('minutesDifference: ' + minutesDifference) 
}
```

I need to find a way to pass a custom date to the function.

Comment: Because `2018, 3, 4, 15, 30, 0` is a series of Number values, not a *customDate*. Within the function you are effectively doing `differenceInMinutes(new Date(2018), new Date())`.

Comment: @RobG Thanks for the explanation. How do I need to format the String to pass a __customDate__ ?

Comment: You shouldn't use the built-in parser at all, though strict adherence to the subset of ISO 8601 described in [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) seems to be OK in modern browsers. But only where the timezone or Z are used, e.g. 2017-05-06T23:42:21+05:30 or 2017-05-06T18:12:21Z.

Comment: Just tried it and it still doesn't put out the correct differenceInMinutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [*date-fns* documentation](https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/differenceInMinutes), *differenceInMinutes* expects to be passed a Date object. In your *getDateTime* function:

```
getDateTime: function (customDate) { 
  var minutesDifference = differenceInMinutes(new Date(customDate), new Date()) 
  console.log('minutesDifference: ' + minutesDifference) 
}
```

you are passing `new Date(customDate)`, and in the call you are passing `getDateTime(2018, 3, 4, 15, 30, 0)`, so the value assigned to *customDate* is `2018`, and you are effectively calling:

```
differenceInMinutes(new Date(2018), new Date());
```

where `new Date(2018)` creates a date for 2,018 milliseconds after the start of 1970-01-01.

> I need to find a way to pass a custom date to the function.

Make sure *customDate* is a Date object, so you can't use

```
getDateTime(2018, 3, 4, 15, 30, 0);
```

You need to use:

```
getDateTime(new Date(2018, 3, 4, 15, 30, 0)); // 2018-04-04 15:30:00
```

You also need to prefix calls to dateFns functions with `dateFns.`, e.g.

```js
// https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.29.0/date_fns.min.js

function getDateTime(customDate) {
  var minutesDifference = dateFns.differenceInMinutes(new Date(customDate), new Date());
  console.log('minutesDifference: ' + minutesDifference) 
}

 getDateTime(new Date(2018, 3, 4, 15, 30, 0)); // 2018-04-04 15:30:00
 // Comparison in plain JS
 console.log(`Plain js: ${(new Date(2018, 3, 4, 15, 30, 0) - Date.now())/6e4 | 0}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.29.0/date_fns.min.js"></script>
<script>dateFns.isToday(new Date())</script>
```